# Same array inside of useEffect and getCoordinates is different when console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps-api-3

### Using GoogleMap API to display custom locations

I have an array of json object called `data` imported; it has a property called address. Google map api looks up coordinates of the address property and should generates custom Markers from an array called locations.

But the value of locations inside `fetchLocations()` and `getCoordinates`, are different when I console.log, although the both represent the same variable.

What did I do wrong?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, InfoWindowF, MarkerF } from "@react-google-maps/api"
import { data } from './data'

const API_KEY = "1234567890"

export default function MyComponent() {

  const { isLoaded }: any = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: API_KEY,
  })

  const result : any[] = [];
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState(result);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocations = async () => {
      const locations = await Promise.all(data.map(getCoordinates));
      console.log("Locations in fetchLocations", locations)
    };
    fetchLocations();
  }, []);


const getCoordinates = async (obj: any) => {
  const objData = await fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + obj.address + '&key=' + API_KEY)
  const response = await objData.json()
      const latitude = response.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      const longitude = response.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      const position = { 'lat': latitude, 'lng': longitude }
      locations.push(position)
      console.log("Locations in get Cooordinate", locations)
}


  if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
      <GoogleMap
        zoom={11}
        center={{ lat: 35.685661305110415, lng: 139.75255896834707 }}
        mapContainerClassName='w-full h-[32em] m-2 rounded-lg'
      >
        <>
          {locations.map(location=>{
            return(
              <>
                <MarkerF
                  position={{ lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng }}
                />              
              </>
            )
          })
          }        
        </>
      </GoogleMap>
      <button onClick={() => { setSelected(!selected) }}>Click</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `locations` array should never be changed in any way. It's supposed to be immutable. The only thing that is able to change it is the `setLocations` function.

Instead of `locations.push(position)` do:

```
setLocations([...locations, position])
```

Also, `getCoordinates` is not returning anything. It should return the same value sent to `setLocations`:

```js
return [...locations, position]
```